# How to build clang with libc++ as default via LLVMs build_docker_image.sh?

Tags: docker, clang, llvm, libc++

I want to build a docker container with clang 6 and libc++ as default C++ standard library. I want to include (and use) the LLVM project clang, libcxx, libcxxabi, lld and compiler-rt.

To set libc++ as default I used the CMAKE option `CLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++` (and additionally `DCLANG_DEFAULT_RTLIB=compiler-rt` to default to compiler-rt). The first stage build does work, but it seems that libc++ is not installed:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm.git
$ cd llvm
$ git checkout release_60
$ utils/docker/build_docker_image.sh -s debian8 \
    -d "clang" -t "6" --branch branches/release_60 \
    -p compiler-rt -p libcxxabi -p libcxx -p clang \
    -i stage2-install-compiler-rt \
    -i stage2-install-libcxxabi \
    -i stage2-install-libcxx \
    -i stage2-install-clang \
    -i stage2-install-clang-headers -- \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++ \
    -DCLANG_DEFAULT_RTLIB=compiler-rt \
    -DLIBCXXABI_USE_LLVM_UNWINDER=YES \
    -DCLANG_ENABLE_BOOTSTRAP=ON \
    -DBOOTSTRAP_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DBOOTSTRAP_CLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++ \
    -DBOOTSTRAP_CLANG_DEFAULT_RTLIB=compiler-rt \
    -DBOOTSTRAP_LIBCXX_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
    -DBOOTSTRAP_LIBCXXABI_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
    -DCLANG_BOOTSTRAP_TARGETS="install-compiler-rt;install-libcxxabi;install-libcxx;install-clang;install-clang-headers"
```

On second stage build I get:

```
[...]
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 6.0.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 6.0.1
-- The ASM compiler identification is unknown
-- Found assembler: /tmp/clang-build/build/./bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /tmp/clang-build/build/./bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /tmp/clang-build/build/./bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /tmp/clang-build/build/./bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /tmp/clang-build/build/./bin/clang++ -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:44 (message):
  The C++ compiler "/tmp/clang-build/build/./bin/clang++" is not able to
  compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /tmp/clang-build/build/tools/clang/stage2-bins/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/ninja" "cmTC_d8e88"

  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8e88.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o

  [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_d8e88

  FAILED: : && /tmp/clang-build/build/./bin/clang++
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8e88.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_d8e88 && :

  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++

  clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
  invocation)

  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:45 (project)
[...]
```

A single stage build seems to be done successfully:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm.git
$ cd llvm
$ git checkout release_60
$ utils/docker/build_docker_image.sh -s debian8 \
    -d "clang-1stage" -t "6" --branch branches/release_60 \
    -p compiler-rt -p libcxxabi -p libcxx -p clang \
    -i install-compiler-rt \
    -i install-libcxxabi \
    -i install-libcxx \
    -i install-clang \
    -i install-clang-headers -- \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++ \
    -DCLANG_DEFAULT_RTLIB=compiler-rt
```

But when I run the container there are also problems with linking:

```
$ docker run -it clang:6
root@1e95a7ffe57a:/# echo "#include <iostream>" > main.cpp
root@1e95a7ffe57a:/# echo "int main(){ std::cout << \"Hello World\\n\"; }" >> main.cpp
root@1e95a7ffe57a:/# clang++ main.cpp 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/main-7d03e7.o: undefined reference to symbol '_Unwind_Resume@@GCC_3.0'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one other LLVM project, [libunwind](https://bcain-llvm.readthedocs.io/projects/libunwind/en/latest).

LLVM's libunwind provides a lightweight stack unwinding interface and is tightly coupled with libcxx and libcxxabi.

You should check out libunwind into the `projects` folder, and it should be automatically picked by LLVM. You may also need to add `-DLIBCXXABI_USE_LLVM_UNWINDER=YES` to CMake command line.

Helpful link: [Clang 8 documentation - Assembling a Complete Toolchain](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Toolchain.html#unwind-library).

Comment: This solves the one stage build and gives me a working setup – thank you for that! The two stage build still gets the same error. Maybe a bug in the build scripts?

Comment: @BenjaminBuch sure :-) Do you mean, second stage failure error message, is the same as in the first stage - undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume`? Try inspecting `CMakeOutput.log` and `CMakeError.log` from the second stage - they be more explicit to what fails exactly